# Not able to load .dae file while creating a SCNScene object in ARKit

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I am trying to load a .dae file with the help of the following line of code:

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/bench.dae")
```

But, when I run my project, the app is crashing because the variable scene is nil.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There may be many things that cause the issue. Can you please upload your project on GitHub or some other site?

Comment: I am sorry but I can't upload the project to GitHub as this code doesn't belong to me. Can you please specify the things that could have gone wrong?

Comment: It's likely that at the point where you try to use the scene object, it wasn't initialized yet, or that you're reading the wrong instance, or that you didn't add art.scnassets to the copied bundle resources... it's impossible to tell from a line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem was with the .dae file's size/orientation. I rotated it by 90 degrees and scaled the image down and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is pretty old, but in case anyone faces this issue like i had yesterday, here is what I did to fix the issue. I thought issue was in format, so I tried .scn model but with copying it in main directory and it worked, then guessed issue was in directory, so I copied my .dae file to main directory  of project then re-added it under copy-bundle-resources from build phases and it worked perfectly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add art.scnassets to Copy Bundle Resources

[image]